# How can I redirect a route using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I use group to help visualize my project's routes.php, now the problem is

for example, when a user access to "/dir", I want to make it be redirected to "/dir/ele"

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dir'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ele'], function () {
        Route::controller('/', 'dir\eleController');
    });
    Redirect::route('ele');
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: looks like you forgot to return the response: `return Redirect::route('ele');`. can you try this?

Comment: yes, and it seems that the problem still exist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route `dir/ele` is going to a controller, but you are doing the redirect in your routes.php instead of in the controller.

You should use a closure route and do everything in the routes.php or use a controller and move the redirect to the controller:

Closure route in routes.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dir'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ele'], function () {
        Route::get('/', function() {
            return Redirect::to('ele');
        });
    });
});
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dir'], function () {
    Route::get('ele', function(){
        return Redirect::to('ele');
    });
});
```

Or use the controller way:

Routes.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dir'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ele'], function () {
        Route::controller('/', 'eleController@redirect');
    });
}
```

eleController.php

```
class eleController extends BaseController {
    function redirect() {
        return Redirect::to('ele');
    }
}
```